# Is there a different way to return strings allocated in Rust to C than to use static mut

Tags: c, string, char, rust, ffi

I am writing a POC for a binding to PHP's Zend Engine.

The library must have exactly one entry point that is responsible for creating all necessary structures.

Parts of those structures are `*const ::std::os::raw::c_char` fields.

Right now to allocate each string I am using the following construct:

```
static mut BUILD_ID: Option<CString> = None;

// then in my function:
unsafe {
    BUILD_ID = Some(CString::new(self.build_id).unwrap());

    Box::new(zend_module_entry {
        build_id: match BUILD_ID {
            Some(ref x) => x.as_ptr(),
            None => panic!(),
        },
    })
}
```

To deallocate the memory I need:

```
unsafe {
    let _ = BUILD_ID.take().unwrap();
}
```

Is there a way to do this without `static mut`?

Comment: *must have exactly one entry point that is responsible for creating all necessary structures* — that's known as a "singleton".

Comment: Note that your current code is **not** thread safe, and is likely to have issues. That's why a `static mut` requires `unsafe`.